# How to draw a table using python and then save as a image

Tags: python

Is there a python library that I can use to draw a table and then save it as a image?
The tables are similar to tables the web browsers draw, e.g. a html table.

Comment: So you have a string containing a HTML table?

Comment: You can draw tables with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#table-demo).

Comment: What does "similar" mean? Please post an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can alway draw a table in web page, check the html elements and save the corresponding web content as a html snippet. So this question can be generalized to: How to convert part of web page(html, css, js) into image ?

Hope this helps solve your problem(a list of library mentioned): [Html to image in javascript or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192799/html-to-image-in-javascript-or-python)

Answer (score 0):

pip install pillowdrawtable

You can use this python module to  draw a table in new_image or draw_object of pillow

```
import PIL
from pillowdrawtable.drawtable import Drawtable
text_font =   PIL.ImageFont.truetype("font_path", 100)
header_font =   PIL.ImageFont.truetype("font_path", 90)
table = Drawtable(data=data,
              x=60,
              y=80,
              font=text_font,
              line_spacer=50,
              margin_text=60,
              image_width=5000,
              image_height=1000,
              frame=False,
              grid=False,
              columngrid=True,
              rowgrid=False,
              header=True,
              headerfont=header_font)
table.draw_table()
```